# Initilize a new instance of SerialPort Class, trying to move code out to interfaces

Tags: c#, interface, initialization

I'm pretty new to c# & .NET, I've written a couple of working apps, but need to move out to interfaces (supervisor said so) to make more modular for reuse on further projects. So first one to try is a serial port interface, as below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace TestSensor
{
    public System.IO.Ports.SerialPort serialPort1 = new SerialPort();

    public interface Iserial
    {      
        // guess these are like function prototypes
        bool isOpen(int p);
        //bool open(int serialInstance, string comPortNo, int baud);
        //bool close(int p);
    }

    public class port : Iserial
    {
        public bool isOpen(int port)
        {
            if (port == 1)
            {
                if (serialPort1.IsOpen) return true;
                else return false;
            }
            else if (port == 2)
            {
                if (serialPort2.IsOpen) return true;
                else return false;
            }
            else return false;
        }
    }
}
```

But I can't find a way initialize a new instance of serial port without error, after much search and experimentation. Current try above causes
"CS0116 A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods"
Thanks for looking!

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what the problem is: namespaces can't contain members and your `seralPort1` member is not part of a class. Move it to be part of your `port` class and the error will go away. Also, I'm not sure why you're "guessing" about things. Developers should never not be 100% sure of exactly what their code is doing and why. You should do some reading on interfaces.

Comment: @itsme86 Thanks, I tried loads of different ways, yes I do need to do more reading on everything at the moment, usual problem not enough time to learn, need to get job done

Comment: the "guess" comment was more of a note to self as I figure interfaces out

Answer (score 0):

Thanks itsme86!
As suggested moved to port class and all is good!

```
namespace TestSensor
{


    public interface Iserial
    {      
        bool isOpen(int p);
        //bool open(int serialInstance, string comPortNo, int baud);
        //bool close(int p);
    }

    public class port : Iserial
    {
        public System.IO.Ports.SerialPort serialPort1 = new SerialPort();
        public System.IO.Ports.SerialPort serialPort2 = new SerialPort();

        public bool isOpen(int port)
        {
            if (port == 1)
            {
                if (serialPort1.IsOpen) return true;
                else return false;
            }
            else if (port == 2)
            {
                if (serialPort2.IsOpen) return true;
                else return false;
            }
            else return false;
        }
    }
}
```